# Как получить значение трафика в системе мониторинга по snmp с входным параметром?

Tags: linux, snmp, мониторинг

Пытаюсь разобраться как опрашивать устройства по snmp. Использую инструменты snmpget и snmpwalk из linux-пакета snmp.
Вот допустим мне нужно получить трафик на порту PON-коммутатора, порт идентифицируется по MAC-адресу на порту устройства.
snmpwalk выдаёт значение указанного и всех последующих OID. Команда:

```
snmpwalk -v 2c -c ###### 10.*.*.* ELTEX-LTE8ST::lte8stONTStatReceive
```

выдаст простыню из всех MACов и всех значений трафика
Я могу использовать параметр -On, чтобы представить параметр не  в виде текстовой строки, а в виде OID и грепнуть вывод по MAC-адресу, чтобы вычислить OID для моего MAC, также я сравниваю первые строки вывода:

```
$ snmpwalk -On -v 2c -c ###### 10.*.*.* ELTEX-LTE8ST::lte8stONTStatReceivePONMac | grep 2:0:5e:4:39:64
.1.3.6.1.4.1.35265.1.21.7.1.1.1.1.6.2.0.94.4.57.100 = STRING: 2:0:5e:4:39:64
$ snmpwalk -On -v 2c -c ###### 10.*.*.* ELTEX-LTE8ST::lte8stONTStatReceivePONMac | head -n 1
.1.3.6.1.4.1.35265.1.21.7.1.1.1.1.6.2.0.34.0.34.196 = STRING: 2:0:22:0:22:c4
$ snmpwalk -On -v 2c -c ###### 10.*.*.* ELTEX-LTE8ST::lte8stONTStatReceivePONBytes | head -n 1
.1.3.6.1.4.1.35265.1.21.7.1.1.1.2.6.2.0.34.0.34.196 = Counter64: 26391219106629
```

Аналитическим путём определяю какую цифру нужно поменять, чтобы получить OID, который выдаст трафик на порту с MAC 2:0:22:0:22:c4 и скармливаю этот OID snmpget:

```
$ snmpget -Oqv -v 2c -c ###### 10.*.*.* .1.3.6.1.4.1.35265.1.21.7.1.1.1.2.6.2.0.94.4.57.100
20441240270200
```

Теперь задача как автоматизировать эту аналитику, чтобы можно было получать значение трафика, вводя MAC в качестве входного параметра, но интересует не просто скрипт, нужен xml-файл для системы мониторинга cacti.

Comment: Не могу сказать про приватные MIB, но возможно есть смысл обратиться к стандартным? Посмотрите MIB-таблицу по адресу  .1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1 В ней хранится информация по интерфейсам (.1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10.порт - принятые байты, .1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.16.порт - отправленные байты). То что видно по вашей мибе:.1.3.6.1.4.1.35265.1.21.7.1.1.1.1.6.2.0.34.0.34.196  это 2.0.34.0.34.196 - ваш МАС переведенный в десятичную систему